# How to make hideshow (hs-toggle-hiding) delimit blank lines for comments?

Tags: hideshow

When using hideshow (specifically `hs-hide-initial-comment-block`), I often run into the problem where the very first comment is a license block, followed by a more detailed comment on the purpose of the file.

For example:

```c
/*
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
 * of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
 * Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
 */

/**
 * This file contains functions that solve problem W, part of API X.
 * Take care not to do Y because it can cause issues with Z.
 */
```

As you might guess, I would like to fold only the first comment, but keep all other comments expanded since it's not part of the boiler plate license header.

Is there a way to tread blank lines as delimiters when hiding comments to avoid hiding multiple, unrelated comments at once?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using advice, although it's not trivial, the following code only collapses the first comment block.

```el
(defmacro my-with-advice (fn-orig where fn-advice &rest body)
  "Execute BODY with WHERE advice on FN-ORIG temporarily enabled."
  `
  (let ((fn-advice-var ,fn-advice))
    (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (advice-add ,fn-orig ,where fn-advice-var)
        ,@body)
      (advice-remove ,fn-orig fn-advice-var))))

(defun my-c-comment-end-skip-backward (pos)
  (cond ;; Check for "/*".
    ((and (eq (char-before pos) ?/) (eq (char-before (- pos 1)) 42))
      (- pos 2))
    (t
      pos)))

(defun my-comment-bounds ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((state (syntax-ppss))
        (point-init (point)))

    ;; We may be at the comment start, which isn't considered a comment.
    (unless (nth 4 state)
      (save-excursion
        (skip-syntax-forward "^-")
        (let ((state-test (syntax-ppss)))
          (when (and (nth 4 state-test) (<= point-init (nth 8 state-test)))
            (setq state state-test)))))

    (when (nth 4 state)
      (let ((start (nth 8 state)))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char start)
          (forward-comment 1)
          (skip-syntax-backward ">")
          (cons start (point)))))))

(defun my-hs-hide-initial-comment-block (orig-fun &rest args)
  (my-with-advice 'hs-inside-comment-p
    :around
    (lambda (fn)
      (save-excursion
        (save-restriction
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (skip-chars-forward " \t\n\f")
          (let ((bounds (my-comment-bounds)))
            (when bounds
              (narrow-to-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
          (funcall fn))))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(with-eval-after-load 'hideshow
  (advice-add 'hs-hide-initial-comment-block
              :around #'my-hs-hide-initial-comment-block))
```